# Postgresql REPL save query result into variable

Tags: postgresql

In [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) REPL it's possible to do something like this:

```
set @x = 1;
set @d = (select now());
select @x, @d;
+------+---------------------+
| @x   | @d                  |
+------+---------------------+
|    1 | 2018-11-22 16:38:11 |
+------+---------------------+
```

Now I try to do same in [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) REPL. I've found this:

```
set var.x = 1;
select current_setting('var.x');
```

And it works, but I can't find the way how to store query result into variable. I've tried this:

```
set var.d = (select now());
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: set var.d = (select now());
                    ^

select now() into var.d;
ERROR:  schema "var" does not exist

select now() into d;
-- creates new table, which is wrong

d := select now();
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "d"
LINE 1: d := select now();
```

Could you please help find the solution? I'm ussing `psql (PostgreSQL) 10.5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure if this is what you are looking for, but there is this a way. 
You can generate a result and store it to a variable like so:

```
\set x 1
select now() \gset
select :x, :'now';
```

Result will be:

```
 ?column? |           ?column?
----------+-------------------------------
        1 | 2018-11-22 19:50:38.391587+02
(1 row)
```